# Writing Kafka Streaming results on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I wrote a Kafka Streaming application that writes results on local files using the code:

```
source.mapValues(record -> finall(record)).mapValues(record -> Arrays.deepToString(record))
            .writeAsText(PATH);
```

Trying to save data on HDFS, using the command:

```
source.mapValues(record -> finall(record)).mapValues(record -> Arrays.deepToString(record))
            .writeAsText(hdfs://localhost:54310/output);
```

it errors:

```
Unable to write stream to file at [hdfs://localhost:54310/output] hdfs:/localhost:54310/output (No such file or directory)
```

Is there any way to write Kafka Streaming results on HDFS?

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid this pattern, and instead write from KStreams back to a Kafka topic, and simply stream that topic to HDFS using the [Kafka Connect HDFS connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html). This way you decouple your stream processing from writing the data elsewhere.

Comment: Is your proposed strategy more efficient?

Comment: What if I insist on writing HDFS directly from Kafka Streaming? Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible, but you need to create a HDFS client in your code manually. For example, you can use `.foreach()` instead of `writeAsText()`. Note, those writes must be sync writes -- otherwise, you might loose data in case if failure. Thus, writing back to Kafka and use Connect as suggested by Robin is the recommended pattern.